# on MAC, I have to show a busy window with a cancel button and spinner

Tags: macos, spinner, nswindowcontroller

On MAC using XCODE and Objective-C, I need to display a small "*BUSY*" window containing a spinner and a cancel button. This will prevent the user doing anything else in my application until I finished the long operation, however if they click cancel it should stop the operation.

I tried creating a simple `NSWindowController` based window with a cancel button and making the window modal, like so....

`-(void) start_long_operation {`
...
...

```
[self showBusy];
return; // return to continue the long operation
}
```

// throw up a "busy" dialog box so user cant do anything until done

```
-(void) showBusy {  
    BusyNSWindow *loadingView = [[LoadingView alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"LoadingView"];<br>
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:loadingView.window];  
}
```

// if cancel clicked, signal to stop long operation, close "busy" dialog box

```
-(IBAction) cancel
{
// cancel was clicked inside the "busy" dialog box so signal process to stop long operation
}
```

but what happens is that it stays inside the `[[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow:loadingView.window]` and doesnt return. I want it to return so that it can continue the long processing while the "busy" dialog box is up, so this wont work.

Anybody knows how to create a small "busy" window that has a cancel button and a spinner, preventing the user from clicking outside that window until the operation is completed, but allowing the rest of the program to continue normally so that it can process the long operation?

-rough_neck

Answer (score 0):

Long operations should never be done on the main thread anyway. Use `NSOperation` and `NSOperationQueue` for the long-running operation, so it runs in the background, and then the modal window will work fine.

Another alternative, but it's much less convenient, is to use a "modal session". See the `-beginModalSessionForWindow:`, `-runModalSession:`, and `-endModalSession:` methods of `NSApplication`. For that, you'd have to break up the long-running operation into quick-running steps that can be invoked sequentially.